# Current Host Name for Scheduled Task

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Is there any way to determine the host name from within a Sitecore Scheduled Task?

I found that within an ASP.NET MVC page for Sitecore 9.3, I can peer into the current `HttpContext` via `Sitecore.Context.HttpContext`.

However, it does not seem possible from within the implementation of a Scheduled Task -- `Sitecore.Context.HttpContext` just returns `null`.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible. What will the hostname allow you to do that a config setting can't accomplish?

Comment: @MichaelWest I will have to use environment-specific config settings if I can't determine the host name at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl/dr is that you can't.

Scheduled tasks don't run within a request context, they run within the context of the `shell` website defined in the `siteDefinition` section of the config.

Comment: Understood. But even the `shell` website should have an `HttpContext`, right?

Comment: No. It runs in a background process. There is no request that kicks it off.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the `SiteContext` for your site and then retrieve the `hostName` in Sitecore Scheduled Task `Execute` Method.

Site configuration

```
<sites>
  ...
  <site name="mysite" hostName="mysite.com|www.mysite.com" scheme="http" ... .../>
  ...
</sites>
```

Get `hostname` using this code.

```
var sitecoreContext  = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("mysite");
string hostname = sitecoreContext.HostName;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Sumit -- but that will only give the patterns that we prescribed in the `<site>` definition. I need the actual runtime host name.

Comment: You can't get the actual runtime hostname in schedule task. You have to get it like this or get it from config setting.